# mongodb join-like query with two collections and a where clause

Tags: mongodb, join, where-clause

Suppose we have following collections in a database:

```
db.documents.insert([{'name': 'A'}, {'name': 'B'}, {'name': 'C'}])
db.fragments.insert([{'value:': 'A1', doc_name: 'A'}, {'value:': 'A2', doc_name: 'A'},
                     {'value:': 'B1', doc_name: 'B'}, {'value:': 'B2', doc_name: 'B'},
                     {'value:': 'C1', doc_name: 'C'}, {'value:': 'C2', doc_name: 'C'}])
```

where `documents` collection stores the names of the documents (and other stuff omitted in this example), `fragments` collections refers by `doc_name` to a document related to the fragment.

Now, if I only want to consider a subset of documents

```
> db.documents.find().limit(2)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a3bf49da25160ad6f076"), "name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a3bf49da25160ad6f077"), "name" : "B" }
```

then how can I see the fragments of associated to these selected documents, so I would get

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a3bf49da25160ad6f079"), "value:" : "A1", "doc_name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a3bf49da25160ad6f07a"), "value:" : "A2", "doc_name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a3bf49da25160ad6f07b"), "value:" : "B1", "doc_name" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d1a3bf49da25160ad6f07c"), "value:" : "B2", "doc_name" : "B" }
```

---

As a solution, I was thinking that I should store the document names in an array, something like `var docnames = ???` such that

```
> docnames
[ "A", "B" ]
```

and then trying to use this array in a where clause, something like

```
> db.fragments.find({$where: function(x) { return (this.doc_name in docnames)}})
error: {
        "$err" : "ReferenceError: docnames is not defined near 'c_name in docnames)}' ",
        "code" : 16722
}
```

But as I am very new to mongodb, so I am having trouble figuring it out. I believe this could be done as a one-liner as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.fragments.find( { 'doc_name': { $in : ['A' , 'B'] } } );
```

Execute this commands in `mongo`:

```
var f = db.documents.find().limit(2) , n = [];
for (var i = 0; i < f.length(); i++) n.push(f[i]['name']);
db.fragments.find( { 'doc_name': { $in : n } } );
```

Comment: Ok, that works, if I have `var docnames = ['A', 'B']` and then do `db.fragments.find({doc_name: {$in: docnames}})`. But how to get `docnames` array from the first query?

Comment: Closest thing I have is `> db.documents.find({}, {'name': 1, '_id': 0}).limit(2)`, which gives
`{ "name" : "A" }
{ "name" : "B" }`