# MongoDB - query with two collections

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get hold of MongoDB and have been experimenting with some basic queries on a single collection but I would like to use two collections in my queries by linking them somehow. I have the below document with information of a movie,

Movies:

```
{
      id:  1, 
      title: "abc", 
      release_data: "xxxx",
      IMDBURL: "qwe", 
      genre: ["xx","yy's","zz"]
}
```

and the below type of document in another collection which has information about a user and an embedded document with the movies he has rated as well as the rating itself.

Users:

```
{
      id:  1, 
      age: xx, 
      gender: "Y", 
      occupation: "abc", 
      zip_code: "asd", 
      movies:[
      { movie: 1, rating: 5 } , 
      { movie: 2, rating: 3 }, 
      { movie: 3, rating: 4 }, 
      { movie: 4, rating: 3 }
      ]
}
```

How would I make a query that returns the title of a movie that has been rated a 5 at least one time? Thank you.

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array)

Comment: [This is more helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067464/mongodb-join-like-query-with-two-collections-and-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

> MongoDB: No JOINS, no transactions

Funny enough, I have never needed either of them. As with your example, you basically have to ask yourself what you need to have answered and *model your data accordingly*.

- Which movies have been rated at least five times?
- For those movies, what are the names?

Given your data model, you don't even get away with ordinary queries: you need an aggregation. With the following dataset:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c8e58ee99e5c4e87ec3a4e"), "age" : 22, "gender" : "Y", "occupation" : "abc", "zip_code" : "asd", "movies" : [ { "movie" : 1, "rating" : 5 }, { "movie" : 2, "rating" : 3 }, { "movie" : 3, "rating" : 4 }, { "movie" : 4, "rating" : 3 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c8e598e99e5c4e87ec3a4f"), "age" : 22, "gender" : "Y", "occupation" : "abc", "zip_code" : "asd", "movies" : [ { "movie" : 1, "rating" : 5 }, { "movie" : 2, "rating" : 3 }, { "movie" : 3, "rating" : 4 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c8e599e99e5c4e87ec3a50"), "age" : 22, "gender" : "Y", "occupation" : "abc", "zip_code" : "asd", "movies" : [ { "movie" : 1, "rating" : 5 }, { "movie" : 2, "rating" : 3 }, { "movie" : 3, "rating" : 4 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c8e59ae99e5c4e87ec3a51"), "age" : 22, "gender" : "Y", "occupation" : "abc", "zip_code" : "asd", "movies" : [ { "movie" : 1, "rating" : 5 }, { "movie" : 2, "rating" : 3 }, { "movie" : 3, "rating" : 4 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c8e59be99e5c4e87ec3a52"), "age" : 22, "gender" : "Y", "occupation" : "abc", "zip_code" : "asd", "movies" : [ { "movie" : 1, "rating" : 5 }, { "movie" : 2, "rating" : 3 }, { "movie" : 3, "rating" : 4 } ] }
```

You can find the movies matching your criteria with the following aggregation

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  { $unwind:"$movies"},
  { $group:{ _id:"$movies.movie", ratings:{ $sum:1 }}},
  { $match:{ ratings:{ $gte:5}}},
  { $project:{ _id:1 }}
])
```

Which will return documents looking like this

```
{ "_id" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

matching the sample data above. Now, with those, you can look up the movie names in the according collection.

### The aggregation, dissected

**`db.movies.aggregate([`**

- **[`{ $unwind:"$movies"},`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)**: Array contents can nor be inspected directly in a way helpful to us here, so we need to deconstruct the array. For each array item, the parent document is basically copied.
- **[`{ $group:{ _id:"$movies.movie", ratings:{ $sum:1 }}},`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)**: We increment the counter **`ratings`**, each time a particular movie is found. So each time a movie rating is found for a particular movie, the counter is incremented.
- **[`{ $match:{ ratings:{ $gte:5}}},`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)**: we only want documents which have been rated at least 5 times
- **[`{ $project:{ _id:1 }}`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)**: Last but not least, since we only want the IDs of the movies, we remove everything else.

**`])`**

To see what the individual stage does, simply remove the stages following it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. I would like the data obtained from the aggregation to be stored in a var movieIds. This way I can iterate through it with movieIds.length() and compare id values with the movies collection. But the movieIds won't have the length() method like it would if it was a product of a find().  Just to be consistent, the aggregation you posted above takes place in db.users and not db.movies.

Comment: Well, MY collection was called db.movies ;) And obvisouly, I don't get your use case. Why store something in a document when you can store it in a dedicated collection using the $out stage, answering one answer properly?.