# Mongo PHP join data from another collection and update doc - like SQL JOIN

Tags: php, mongodb

I need help with MongoDb with PHP driver.

I have 4 collections:

1. order_aproved :

   ```
   {
      "order_id" : mongoId ,
      "user_id":num ,
      "order_date":mongoDate ,
      "requset" : string 
   }
   ```
2. orders_rejected :

   ```
   {
     "order_id" : mongoId,
     "user_id" : num ,
     "order_date" : mongoDate ,
     "requset" : string
   }
   ```
3. users :

   ```
   {
     "user_id" : mongoId,
     "username" : num ,
     "last_order" : mongoDate ,
     "num_orders" : num,
     "last_order"
   }
   ```
4. orders_log :

   ```
   {
      "order_id" : mongoId  ,
      "order_date" : mongoDate ,
      "status" : boolen ,
      "user_id" : num
   }
   ```

Every approved/rejected order, I update the `num_orders` on user document
that have a new/rejected order. So that number is always changing
and log that order on `orders_log`.

I need to fetch all orders approved/rejected on `orders_log` by list of users `[array]` with condition and get the orders count `num_orders` and last order date for that user by the order from this user

I am doing it like this:

```
$cursor = $orders->find()->sort(array("order_date" => -1))->limit(15);
$array = iterator_to_array($cursor,false);

$users_for_aproved = ["123","124","125"];
$users_for_rejcted = ["112","113","114"];

$js = "function() { if ( this.requset )  { return this.requset.length > 0 } }"; 

$query1 = array( '$and' => array(
    array("user_id" => array('$in'=> $users_for_aproved)),
    array('$where' => $js )
));

$query1 = array( '$and' => array(
    array("user_id" => array('$in'=> $users_for_rejcted)),
    array('$where' => $js )
));

$query_or = array('$or' => array($query,$query1);

$cursor = $orders_log->find($query_or)->sort(array("order_date" => -1))->limit(15);
$array = iterator_to_array($cursor,false);

for (  $x=0; $x < count($array) ; $x++ ) {

    $query = array( "user_id" => $order["user_id"] );
    $cursor = $orders->find($query)->limit(1);
    $array = iterator_to_array($cursor,false);

    $order_count = $array[0]["num_orders"];
    $array[$x]["order_count"] = $order_count;
}

return $array;
```

It's working but its not very efficient , i need a way to fetch data from another collection and add the num_orders to the doc that i have find without a use form anther query

like SQL JOIN but on mongo and php driver
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb join-like query with two collections and a where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067464/mongodb-join-like-query-with-two-collections-and-a-where-clause)

Comment: i need mongo with php and your answer is just mongo, and its not like my problom, thanks

Comment: I'm a little lost on the explanation. Where does "list of users" come from? Is that an external input or meant to be retrieved from one of the collections? Do you actually mean that there is some sort of selection that needs to be done from "approved' and "rejected" to get the list? Are we just basically adding "approved" **minus** "rejected" to the current user `num_orders`? Also this is just collecting data for a later "update", Right? Semi related is why is `"requset"` being checked for `> 0` length? And can that be done differently?

Comment: the list come from the full query its array with ids[ 123,456,2134,345 ], the requset is a string i need to return only docs that have length of "requset" > 0 so i wil not get orders that have no "requset" srting its just a condtion

Comment: @user2843540 Please note the `@` "thingy" there in the comment. This is how you address your message to someone on StackOverflow. There are still some very unclear points in your question. I listed them in the comment before. You need to edit your question and explain each of those points. You talk about a "join" but it is not clear what exactly needs to be be "joined" in your point of view. Read my comment again and please try to expand your explanation **in the question**. Message to me when you have done that so I know you have made changes. Please.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve gain in performance in this case:

1. create an index on MongoDB:
   `db.order_aproved.createIndex( { user_id: 1 } )`
   You may create the above index either in the above way, or in the background:
   `db.order_aproved.createIndex( { user_id: 1 }, { background: true } )`
   In the last case, the creation will be slower, but it will not bother the currently ongoing operations on the database. If you may afford it, I think you should better create an index not in the background, esp. if are not running this script on the Production Database
2. re-design the collections, so that instead of the different collections, joined by some ID, you should create **embedded documents** inside the main document, thus eliminating the need to perform any operations, similar to `JOIN`s in RDBMSs.

Of the above, simplest and more straight forward solution in your case, seems to me the first one. Choosing it, you will also avoid performance losses in updates for embedded documents